# Xamarin: List View Item ItemClick event triggers multiple times

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm working on an app where I load data from my website using web services when I click a back or next button it will load again the data from the web service and then load those data on my custom PostAdapter class then load that adapter to my list view item

```
private async void LoadPosts(int year, int month){
    IPostService postService = new PostService();

    var posts = await postService.GetPosts(year, month);

    PostAdapter adapter = new PostAdapter(Activity, posts.ToList();

    _lstView.Adapter = adapter;

    _lstView.ItemClick += _lstView_ItemClick;
}

private void _lstView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e){
    var item = _lstView.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position).Cast<Post>();

    var bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.PutInt("post_id", item.ID);

    var nextFragment = new PostDetailFragment { Arguments = bundle };

    var fragmentTransaction = this.Activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, nextFragment).Commit();
}

private void _btnPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    _selectedDate = _selectedDate.AddMonths(-1);

    LoadPosts(_selectedDate.Year, _selectedDate.Month);
}
```

Now when I clicked previous button 3 times, then click item list view once. It will trigger 3 times the item click event of list view item. Any ideas?

Comment: you should set `_lstView.ItemClick` only once. and not when you `LoadPosts`. Every time you load the posts, you're adding another itemClick handler.

Comment: You are correct, thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move this line outside of your `LoadPosts` method, probably to whatever the equivalent of the `onCreate` is

```
_lstView.ItemClick += _lstView_ItemClick;
```

The reason you're getting 3 event clicks is because every time the posts are loading, you're adding another event handler to the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Register the event in your App.cs and call other Dependencyservice methods from your MVVM.

For Example:

Step 1: I have IDownloader interface with one event(**OnFileDownloaded**) and one method(**DownloadFile**).

Step 2: Register event handler in "App.cs".

Step 3: Call "DownloadFile" function in your MVVM class.

After file download "OnFileDownloaded" event will fire automatically.

```
public interface IDownloader
{
    void DownloadFile(string url, string folder);
    event EventHandler<DownloadEventArgs> OnFileDownloaded;
}

public class DownloadEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool FileSaved = false;
    public string FilePath = string.Empty;

    public DownloadEventArgs(bool fileSaved, string filePath)
    {
        FileSaved = fileSaved;
        FilePath = filePath;
    }
}
```

**For Android**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Downloader_Droid))]
namespace Antsig.Droid.Services
{
    public class Downloader_Droid : IDownloader
    {
        public event EventHandler<DownloadEventArgs> OnFileDownloaded;
        string pathToNewFolder = string.Empty;
        public void DownloadFile(string url, string folder)
        {
            pathToNewFolder = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, folder);

            if(!Directory.Exists(pathToNewFolder)){Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToNewFolder);}

            try
            {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
                string pathToNewFile = Path.Combine(pathToNewFolder, Path.GetFileName(url));
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), pathToNewFile);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (OnFileDownloaded != null)
                    OnFileDownloaded.Invoke(this, new DownloadEventArgs(false,""));
            }
        }
        private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                if (OnFileDownloaded != null)
                    OnFileDownloaded.Invoke(this, new DownloadEventArgs(false,""));
            }
            else
            {
                if (OnFileDownloaded != null)
                    OnFileDownloaded.Invoke(this, new DownloadEventArgs(true, pathToNewFolder));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**For iOS**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Downloader_iOS))]
namespace Antsig.iOS.Services
{
    public class Downloader_iOS : IDownloader
    {
        public event EventHandler<DownloadEventArgs> OnFileDownloaded;
        string pathToNewFolder = string.Empty;

        public void DownloadFile(string url, string folder)
        {

            pathToNewFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), folder);

            try
            {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
                string pathToNewFile = Path.Combine(pathToNewFolder, Path.GetFileName(url));
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), pathToNewFile);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (OnFileDownloaded != null){  OnFileDownloaded.Invoke(this, new DownloadEventArgs(false,"")); }
            }
        }

        private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                if (OnFileDownloaded != null){ OnFileDownloaded.Invoke(this, new DownloadEventArgs(false,"")); }
            }
            else
            {
                if (OnFileDownloaded != null){ OnFileDownloaded.Invoke(this, new DownloadEventArgs(true, pathToNewFolder)); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In App.cs file**

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    //Dependencyservice interface
    IDownloader downloader = null;

    protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
        downloader = DependencyService.Get<IDownloader>();
        downloader.OnFileDownloaded += OnFileDownloaded;

        base.OnResume();
    }

    private void OnFileDownloaded(object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.FileSaved)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("File Saved", "The PDF have downloaded.", "OK");
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { DependencyService.Get<IToast>().Show("Error while saving the file"); });
        }
    }
}
```

**Call DependencyService in MVVM class file**

```
public class VideoViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    IDownloader downloader = null;

    public VideoViewModel()
    {
        downloader = DependencyService.Get<IDownloader>();
    }

    private async Task DownloadPdfCommandExecuteAsync(string pdf)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pdf))
        {

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => 
            {
                if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android) { DependencyService.Get<IToast>().Show("File downloading..."); await Task.Yield(); }
            });

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                downloader.DownloadFile(pdf, "Antsig");
            });
            if (!isDownloading)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<IToast>().Show("File Saved Successfully.");
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```